# How to print the end of the first page

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, printing, datagridview

Well, I have a system to print a `DataGridView`. In some cases, the `DataGridView` exceeds the limit of the page, and I lost the last rows, and I can't lost these rows. I'm already tried to use the `e.HasMorePages`, but I get a infinite loop of printing pages... Here's my code, some things are in Portuguese, this is because I'm Brazilian.

```
private void pd_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs ev)
    {
            StringFormat stringFormat = new StringFormat();
            stringFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            stringFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
            string header = label1.Text;
            Graphics g = ev.Graphics;
            Font font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10, FontStyle.Regular);
            Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black);
            float fontHeigth = font.GetHeight();
            int i = 1;
            Pen pe = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {

                if (i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pe, 10, startY + fontHeigth + 2 + offset, 779, startY + fontHeigth + 2 + offset);
                }
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["day"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 2, startY + offset);
                offset = offset + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                i++;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["hist"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 110, startY + offset1);
                offset1 = offset1 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["descricao"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 340, startY + offset2);
                offset2 = offset2 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["empresa"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 480, startY + offset3);
                offset3 = offset3 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }
            double total = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                string valor = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["valor"].Value);

                Double value;
                if (Double.TryParse(valor, out value))
                    valor = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value);
                else
                    valor = String.Empty;

                g.DrawString(valor, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, startY + offset4);
                offset4 = offset4 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                total = total + value;
            }

            string tot = total.ToString();

            Double value1;
            if (Double.TryParse(tot, out value1))
                tot = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value1);
            else
                tot = String.Empty;

            g.DrawString("Total de créditos: ", new Font("Times New Roman", 11, FontStyle.Underline), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 550, startY + offset - 20);
            g.DrawString(tot, new Font("Times New Roman", 11, FontStyle.Underline), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, startY + offset - 20);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, startY + 24 + offset, 779, startY + 24 + offset);
            Image img = Properties.Resources.logo_ropy_novo;
            img = resizeImage(img, new Size(250, 80));
            if (!(offset > ev.MarginBounds.Bottom))
            {
                g.DrawImage(img, new Point(10, 10));
                g.DrawString(header, new Font("Calibri", 10), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 425, 10, stringFormat);
            }
            Font fnt = new Font("Calibri", 14);

            Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 4);
            p.StartCap = LineCap.Round;
            p.EndCap = LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
            g.DrawLine(p, 10, 125, 22, 125);
            g.DrawString("Créditos", new Font("Times New Roman", 15, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 24, 114);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, 137, 779, 137);
            g.DrawString("Dia", new Font("Times New Roman", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, 140);
            g.DrawString("Histórico", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 110, 140);
            g.DrawString("Descrição", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 340, 140);
            g.DrawString("Empresa", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 480, 140);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 108, 137, 108, startY + offset - fontHeigth - 7);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 338, 137, 338, startY + offset - fontHeigth - 7);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 478, 137, 478, startY + offset - fontHeigth - 7);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, 137, 10, startY + offset - fontHeigth - 7);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 668, 137, 668, startY + offset);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 779, 137, 779, startY + offset);
            g.DrawString("Valor", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, 140);

            int y = startY + offset;
            g.DrawLine(p, 10, y + 12, 22, y + 12);
            g.DrawString("Débitos", new Font("Times New Roman", 15, FontStyle.Italic), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 24, y);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 668, y, 779, y);
            g.DrawString("Dia", new Font("Times New Roman", 14), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 10, y + 26);
            g.DrawString("Histórico", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 110, y + 26);
            g.DrawString("Descrição", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 340, y + 26);
            g.DrawString("Empresa", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 480, y + 26);
            p.Dispose();
            g.DrawString("Valor", new Font("Times New Roman", 13), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, y + 25);

            fontHeigth = font.GetHeight();
            startX = 10;
            startY = 135 + offset + 23;
            offset = 40;
            offset1 = 40;
            offset2 = 40;
            offset3 = 40;
            offset4 = 40;
            i = 1;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                if (i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count)
                {
                    g.DrawLine(pe, 10, startY + fontHeigth + 2 + offset, 779, startY + fontHeigth + 2 + offset);
                }
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["day"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX + 2, startY + offset);
                offset = offset + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                i++;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["hist"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 110, startY + offset1);
                offset1 = offset1 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }

            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["descricao"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 340, startY + offset2);
                offset2 = offset2 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                g.DrawString(Convert.ToString(row.Cells["empresa"].Value), font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 480, startY + offset3);
                offset3 = offset3 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
            }

            double totaldb = 0;
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
            {
                string valor = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["valor"].Value);

                Double value;
                if (Double.TryParse(valor, out value))
                    valor = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", value);
                else
                    valor = String.Empty;

                g.DrawString(valor, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, startY + offset4);
                offset4 = offset4 + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                offsettotal = offsettotal + (int)fontHeigth + 5;
                totaldb = totaldb + value;
            }

            string totdb = totaldb.ToString();

            Double valuedb;
            if (Double.TryParse(totdb, out valuedb))
                totdb = String.Format(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0:C2}", valuedb);
            else
                totdb = String.Empty;

            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 10, startY + 1, 10, startY + offset - 23);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 108, startY + 1, 108, startY + offset - 23);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 338, startY + 1, 338, startY + offset - 23);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 478, startY + 1, 478, startY + offset - 23);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 668, startY + 1, 668, startY + offset);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 779, startY + 1, 779, startY + offset);

            g.DrawString("Total de débitos: ", new Font("Times New Roman", 11, FontStyle.Underline), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 550, startY + offset - 20);
            g.DrawString(totdb, new Font("Times New Roman", 11, FontStyle.Underline), new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 670, startY + offset - 20);
            g.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.Black), 668, offset + startY, 779, offset + startY);

    }
```

Here's the actual page in the OneNote: 
http://prntscr.com/2ya7xd

Comment: You have to know the printing size. If offsettotal + some_margin exceed the printing size you should create a new page.

Comment: Can you explain how I do it? Please

Answer (score 0):

The `ev.MarginBounds.Height` gives you the height of the page inside the margins. The `DataGridViewRow.Height` gives you the individual row height. Using these information you can check whether you need more pages during printing of each page.

Also drawing row by row would give you much more control on the printing. See [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28046/Printing-of-DataGridView) article for more information.

Sample Code:

Have class level variable   `int rowIndex=0;`

```
int rowTop=ev.MarginBounds.Top;
bool needMorePages=false;
while (rowIndex<= dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1)
{
    DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
    if(rowTop + row.Height >= ev.MarginBounds.Top + ev.MarginBounds.Height)
    {
        needMorePages = true;
        break;
    }
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
    {
        //draw cell content
    }
    rowTop += row.Height;
    rowIndex++;
}
ev.HasMorePages = needMorePages;
```

Comment: I tried this. He create a new page, but the page is blank, he don't draws the last rows whose are not printed in the first page.

Comment: @user3380363 The above code is just a sample. A working example is available in the article I have linked.